# Unknown column civicrm_relationship.is_active while child smart group edit (create temporary table fails)

Tags: database, error, relationships, smartgroups, mysql

There are a parent Smart Group which contains several "child" Smart Groups. All was working a while, until at some time point it starts throw an error, something like

```
 [debug_info] => CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civicrm_temp_group_contact_cache1208
 (SELECT 258 as group_id,  contact_a.id as id  
FROM civicrm_contact contact_a    
LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact 
`civicrm_group_contact-  262,278,261,263,264,265,266,267,268,269,270,271,272,273,274,275`
 ON 
... long query skipped ...
 WHERE civicrm_group_contact.status = 'Removed'
 AND   civicrm_group_contact.group_id = 258 ) ); 
[nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'civicrm_relationship.is_active' 
in 'where clause']
```

Is this a bug?  CiviCRM 4.6.15;

Comment: Seeing this on a 4.6.16 site, did you find a resolution?

Comment: Nope; haven't searched though, just realized it might be an issue with SQL queries when smart group child is also a  smart group. Should have reported, but recent security update has broken things badly, so totally forgot about this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do post back here if you create an issue or make any progress. I'll do likewise.